# I am working in JSF and prime faces 4.0 with maven dependencies

Tags: maven, jsf-2, primefaces

I am getting this error again and again. I have added servlet jars:

```
Oct 15, 2014 1:54:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start INFO: Starting tomcat server Oct 15, 2014 1:54:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29 Oct 15, 2014 1:54:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart SEVERE: Exception starting filter PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825) at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558) at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319) at 
org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

These are the dependencies I have used in my project

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

These are the filters and servlet mappings I have used in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>2097152</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>D:\upload</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Check if servlet-api in your maven dependencies has scope provided. Maybe this is the case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: i have tried but nothing is worked out for me......

Comment: i have added mappings of servlet and filters... and the dependencies i have used... Plz help me wit that

Comment: thanks for your help..... As you said i have missed the scope for dependencies....

Answer (score -1):

This exception happens when you have a jar contains `javax.servlet.*` classes in `WEB-INF\lib` folder of your web app. If you are using maven use provided scope for those dependencies.

Comment: thanks for your help..... As you said i have missed the scope for dependencies....

Answer (score -1):

You need to add following dependancies. Also use letest version.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For More Info. <strike>http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/file-upload-with-primefaces</strike>